# Add element when form field is valid in Vue.js with vee-validate

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, vue.js

Using [vee-validate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/), a Vue.js plugin for form validation, I want to show an image after validation for the input field has passed. As you can see, I tried to do this with `v-show="!errors.has('fname')"`. The problem is, the image will already be shown before the validation takes place, since there are no errors then. How can I show the image when the corresponding input field is valid?

```
<form>
  <input v-validate="{rules: {required: true, alpha: true, min: 3}}"type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/>
  <img v-show="!errors.has('fname')" class="check-icon" src="../../assets/png/check-icon.png" alt="check-icon"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v-show="!errors.has('fname') && input is not empty"
```